# How to update state of nested components when app receive notifications?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

So in my app I have a main component which have switch navigator and then inside switch navigator I have a tab navigator which renders different screens. I have registered notification handler in top component. 
Now the problem is that when notification is received, I want to make some changes on screens inside tab navigator.

I have read about redux which will provide common store so state could be updated but I dont want to use that.
I have also read about lifting state up but in my case i have more nested components so I dont want to do that as well.

So suggest me some way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using react context api. It is simple wrap your top level component with provider and define some veriable and access that variable in any component.